# how do I call a function within a class knowing the function name?

Tags: javascript

I have a function name = "test".

How do I call this.test() function in a class knowing the function name?

I'm guessing I can use the eval() function but that is not working?

How can I call a class function using only the string name in javascript?

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Comment: simply `className['methodeName']()`

Comment: call like :this[name]();

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation.

```
this["test"](/* args */);
```

or

```
name = "test";
this[name](/* args */);
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the function just as a plain function without the object as context, just get the reference to it and call it. Example:

```
var name = "test";
var f = obj[name];
f(1, 2);
```

To call it as a method of the object, get a reference to the function then use the `call` method to call it to set the context. Example:

```
var name = "test";
var f = obj[name];
f.call(obj, 1, 2);
```

If you are inside a method of the object, you can use `this` instead of the object reference `obj` that I used above.

Answer (score 0):

To make you code more safe, I recommend you to check that it  is a function.

```
var a='functionName'
if (typeof this[a]!='function')
  alert('This is not a function')
else
  this[a]()
```